# Pandas error with pivot_table and categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having no fun with this on pandas. I have this Data.Frame:

```
 category1  category2   numeric
0   grey    complete    1
1   grey    complete    2
2   NaN     incomplete  3
3   blue    complete    4
```

And I want to pivot table.

```
p.pivot_table(df, index = 'category1', columns = 'category2', values = 'numeric', aggfunc = 'count')
```

That's ok but a I need add some categories in category1, then I do:

```
df['category1_'] = p.Categorical(df['category1'], categories = ['grey','blue','red'])
```

And now a get:

```
p.pivot_table(df, index = 'category1_', columns = 'category2', values = 'numeric', aggfunc = 'count')

ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

I think there is a problem with NaN values in categorical series but droping NaN:

```
df2 = df.dropna()

p.pivot_table(df2, index = 'category1_', columns = 'category2', values = 'numeric', aggfunc = 'count')

C:\Users\diego_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in _astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
   2671 
   2672         if np.isnan(arr).any():
-> 2673             raise ValueError('Cannot convert NA to integer')
   2674     elif arr.dtype == np.object_ and np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
   2675         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987

ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

I dont know how to solve this: Categorical data with pivot_table doesnt save categories, order and make error when there is NaN values.

Am I so newbie with pandas? or pandas categorical are still in early days?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: The problem appears to be with the categorical data, even if your initial df had no `NaN` values the error still occurs

Comment: This may be fixed already in the dev version, which has a CategoricalIndex

Comment: Yes @TomAugspurger, v0.16.1 (April ??, 2015) -> Support for a CategoricalIndex, a category based index, see here. I'll be waiting and I will come back to see what happend. Thanks.

Comment: Still gives this error on master, even for the first example. I opened an issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10028